# D7 Simple form with an items catalog grid table

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I need a form with a simple items catalog, user will enter quantities for each item and it will auto calculate sub total and total using javascript.

I am looking something like this:

Name: **_**

Email: **_**

Address: **_**

please select your items:

ID | Name   | Price | Quantity | Sub Total

1  | Item 1 | $10   | [**_**]  |

2  | Item 2 | $10   | [**_**]  |

3  | Item 3 | $10   | [**_**]  |

Total               |

[Submit]

Is there some module available to develop this kind of form, or I'll have to develop some custom module? I tried with Webform module but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself with the help of [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform), [webform_table_element module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_table_element) and by implementing a couple of hooks and a little jQuery snippet. A complete howto can be found here:

[Drupal 7 Webform with an item catalog table element](http://helperclass.blogspot.com/2012/06/drupal-7-webform-with-item-catalog.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the Webform module gets you close to the result you want you could try altering the created form and adding additional bits that you need with [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Creating a custom module and form is always an option and will offer you the most flexibility, but it might be quite a bit more work depending of your needs. If you start working with Drupal forms on the code level you can check out the [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) page for a good source of information.